# source multiple files with map

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I outsourced a few sections of my `.vimrc` to `.vim/custom/binds/foo.vim` to seperate binds for different languages. I know about `after` but I want to keep the structure I am currently using.

I often find my self changing mappings in `foo.vim` while working in some `file.foo`, and **don't want to close and reopen `file.foo` file every time I make changes to `foo.vim`**.

I have `noremap \c0 <Esc>:source<Space>~/.vimrc<Enter>` in my `.vimrc` and it performs exactly what I want for the mappings in the rc.

I tried to include `runtime! custom/binds/*.vim` but this does not seem to work. Not even when executed manually.

---

`:help runtime`:

```
When {file} contains wildcards it is expanded to all
                        matching files.  Example:
                                :runtime! plugin/*.vim
```

what am I missing here?

---

edit:

inside my `.vimrc` I `:source ~/.vim/custom/binds/foo.vim`. so sourcing works fine, but I have to do this for every file seperatly.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the standard `.vim/plugin/` and `.vim/ftplugin/{ft}/` ? It's their exact purpose.

- plugins are loaded once when Vim starts
- ftplugins are loaded every time you open a file, or create a new buffer, that matches the associated filetype.

Don't mix up the official *plugins scripts* with the plugins managed by plugin managers. The second kind are just bundles of a set the first kind distributed among specific sub-directories. These specific sub-directories can (and must) also be used for your own configuration.

You'll also be interested in this [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254993/how-to-unload-a-vim-script-after-sourcing-it-and-making-changes-to-it/40257268#40257268) that also discusses reloading scripts -- three reloading solutions are indirectly provided: my `:Reload` helper command, Tim Pope's `vim-scriptstrease`, and Ingo Karkat's `ReloadScript`.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try, but I actually wanted to keep them where they are now. Loading the files on start-up is also not my problem.

I source all relevant files in my .vimrc.

What I wanted to do is to reload all these Scripts WITHOUT reopening the file I am currently working on when I change a relevant .vim file.

Currently I have maped \c0 to :source ~/.vimrc<Enter>.
But that somehow wont run the :source commands inside the .vimrc. So I wanted to include my custom bindings into that binding \c0 to reload all other files as well